# INotifyCollectionChanged's NewItems - cannot use OfType<T> to get data

Tags: c#, linq, inotifycollectionchanged

I am attempting to get some custom objects from the `CollectionChanged` event of a collection which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

```
MyControl_MyCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
  {
    lock(e.NewItems.SyncRoot)
    {
      var myItems = e.NewItems.OfType<MyType>();

      if(myItems.Any())
      {
        //do stuff
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that `myItems` always says "Enumeration yielded no results".

Expanding on debug `e.NewItems.SyncRoot` shows the following:

```
e.NewItems.SyncRoot | {object[1]}
|-[0] | {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<MyType, IMyInterface>}
| |-base ...
| |-Non-public members
| |-Results View | Expanding the Results View...
|   |-[0] | MyType
```

So clearly the data is there. What is the method for retrieving this data?

Comment: Side note: use `.Any()` instead of `.Count() > 0`. You don't care how many items you have (at that point), so why bother counting them all?

Comment: A fair point, will edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a bug in whatever is creating the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` object.

NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs has several constructors. There are two relevant ones here:

- `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction, object)`
- `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction, IList)`

The first describes a change on a single item. The second describes a change on a list of items.

However, the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` constructor has been called as `new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, enumerable)`. `IEnumerable<...>` does not implement `IList`, so the first constructor gets called when the second is the one that should be used.

Do you have control over the code that raises `NotifyCollectionChanged`? If so, use `new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, enumerable.ToList())` instead.

Comment: You sir, are a genious. This was exactly the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> So clearly the data is there

It is clear, that your collection, that was changed, contains items of type `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<MyType, IMyInterface>`, not a `MyType` type.